# Is it possible in batch to make some text pop up that is randomly selected from a list?

Tags: string, batch-file, random

I am working on a program on a flash drive that does lots of things, but the main focus here is on one feature, where I want it to say the computers mood (randomly select a mood text from 10 different mood
texts. I want it to immediatly display it when the option is selected, and it may use external files but
do keep in mind that I am making this on a 16gb Flash Drive so it has to be compatible with the flash drive. It'd probably have to use `%random%` in the code. I am fairly skilled at batch programming, just so you know when you're asking me questions.
Thanks!

Comment: How did I get -2 votes???? Everyone  hates my posts I guess

Comment: @Monacraft ok no need to be a hater and I didn't have any idea what to do so just chill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

### Mood.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Change num to the number of moods
set num=6
set m1=Happy
set m2=Sad
set m3=Crying
set m4=Dead
set m5=Awkward
set m6=Trolling
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

set t=1
set /a t=%random%%%num%
Echo !m%t%!
pause
```

And that should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works as an external file and it looks like it'll work when I put it into my bigger file.

Comment: @Jack Is this helped please mark my answer as correct